# Datatype sizes revision in Programming Languages

Tags: c++, int, size

when and how often do the byte sizes of datatypes change in any programming language? Eg: `int` in `C++` is **4 bytes** from the previous **2 bytes**.

Comment: `int` in the C++ standard is not guaranteed to be any particular length, only at least 16 bits.

Comment: Since the only datatype mentioned in the question is `int`, the marked duplicate question for the C language is more than sufficient to answer this question.